# is dmidecode's max memory report is accurate?

Tags: hp, ram

After googling for a while I've found "sudo dmidecode -t 16,17" to check max amount of memory in my laptops. Based on its report my HP Pavilion g4-1002tu laptop can accept a max of 16GB, while the HP website says it can only handle 8GB.

Funny thing is when I checked my Asus Eee PC R105 Atom N450 which only has 1 slot with a max of 2GB ram it is reported to have 2 slots for ram and can hold 4GB of memory! Even on Intel's website it said max amount of memory is 2GB! Could anyone kindly explain this matter, as I am planning on upgrading my HP g4's memory.

Have a nice day and thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is as accurate as the information your motherboard provides.  When in doubt, go with the specs the manufacturer publishes, since it is more likely they just didn't put the correct information into the bios.

Comment: sincerely thank you for very fast reply. surely I'm very curious since I'm eager to add some more memory to my laptop to maximize the performance. my g4-1002tu already ridiculously upgraded the processor to i7-8720qm, got wondered with no turboboost configuration in bios and the intel's turboboost monitor seems to be shown nothing interesting about the processor I've bought. anyone can confirm that hm65 chipset together with i7-8720qm can accept more than 8gb of ram eg. 16gb or even 32gb? :D thanks again in advance and have a good day. ps: sorry for my english.

Comment: greetings everyone! as per (http://bizsupport1.austin.hp.com/bizsupport/TechSupport/Document.jsp?objectID=c02712028&lang=en&cc=us&taskId=101&prodSeriesId=5046252&prodTypeId=321957) I've upgraded to i7-2820qm and added 16gb ram from amd. so far felt like it runs smooth in linux (kali), but when on windows seems a bit bottleneck. hmmmm.... seems like dmidecode reports is real. any comments, suggestions, or advices. or my laptop start to aging? :D

Comment: When it shows Maximum Capacity: 8 GB and Number Of Devices: 2, can i use 2 8GB modules?

Comment: @JITHINJOSE No. You can use 2 4GB modules. And your motherboard will likely reject a 8GB module.